# "von Englisch nach Deutsch" - why not "zu"?

Tags: word-choice, preposition

Following the About.com article on [zu vs nach](http://german.about.com/library/weekly/aa061900a.htm), I would guess that "from English to German" would be `von Englisch zum Deutsch`, but Google Translate uses `nach` when trying to say 'to a language'. So it seems the correct way is `von Englisch nach Deutsch`.

Is this an exception, or is this indicative of a more general use of `nach` than the ones below.

---

Summarizing `nach` usage in the article:

- 'to' with geographic places, compass and left/right directions
- 'after' (temporal, e.g. *nach der Schule*) and 'according to' (e.g. *nach dem Gesetz*)

Comment: _Aus dem Englischen ins Deutsche._

Comment: We need more Context for the question; a whole sentence at least. "President Kennedy changed from Englisch to German: `Ick bin ein Berliner!`". Hier wäre `von Englisch nach Deutsch` richtig.

Comment: In that context, I'd actually say _vom Englischen ins Deutsche_.

Comment: Er hat während dem Sprechen von Englisch nach Deutsch gewechselt.

Comment: Er hat während dem Sprechen vom Englischen ins Deutsche gewechselt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Von … nach …` is a special construction similar to `from … to …` that cannot be splitted into the single prepositions `von …` and `nach …`. So it's wrong to say either.

> Ich übersetze den Satz nach Deutsch.

or

> Ich übersetze den Satz von Englisch.

You can only say:

> Ich übersetze den Satz von Englisch nach Deutsch.

If you want to only express one part of this, the prepositions `von …` and `nach …` are insuitable. Instead, you need:

> Ich übersetze den Satz ins Deutsche.

and

> Ich übersetze den Satz aus dem Englischen.

This special construction (lets call it "double preposition") `von … nach …` generically describes transitions or directions, one possibility of which is the transition of the language. There are also the double prepositions `von … zu …` and `von … in …` which are used in special cases:

> Ich fahre von mir zu dir.
>
> Ich komme vom Regen in die Traufe.
>
> Ich übersetze vom Deutschen ins Englische.

In General, these double prepositions cannot be split up, but sometimes one part of it can be used as single preposition whilst the other part cannot:

> Ich fahre von Berlin nach Dresden.
>
> Ich fahre nach Dresden.

Both are totally valid sentences. But

> Ich fahre von Berlin.

is not valid except as part of or answer to a question involving the second part.

> Du fährst von wo nach Dresden? Ich fahre von Berlin.
>
> Du fährst von Berlin nach wo?

Comment: "Ich fahre von Berlin nach Dresden." is correct. "Ich fahre nach Dresden" is correct too although I split the supposed special construction. If it is only sometimes a special construction then calling it that makes things more complicated than they are. This was problem number one. "Wie komme ich von hier zu mir?"this does express a transition or direction to, and it is the combination of "von... zu ...". Maybe I am not getting something but then you'd need to be more precise in your answer... until then -1 for 2 obviously wrong claims.

Comment: @Emanuel 1. There is a difference between die special construction "double preposition" of `von … nach …` and the single prepositions `von …` and `nach …`. You cannot say `Ich fahre von Berlin.`, except as an answer to the question `Ach, du fährst nach Dresden. Von wo fährst du denn?`. The `nach` in `Ich fahre nach Dresden.` is not the whole construction split up, but another preposition `nach …`, which just "happens" to use the same word as `von … nach …`. Your second point is valid: If the destination is a person `von … zu …` is used instead.

Comment: first about 2). Person or not is not really the point: "Ich gehe vom Strand zum Hotel/Markt/Konzert/". As for the other part: how can you tell apart the "special construction" from a single combination? How do you explain to a student that "nach Berlin" can be 2 different nachs that just coincidentally look the same? How do you explain "von der Wiege bis zur Bahre", "von dort hinten bis da vorne"? The point that "Ich fahre von..." alone doesn't work is not the preposition but the verb fahren which doesn't work with just an origin.

Comment: "Ich komme von der Arbeit nach Hause" vs "Ich komme von der Arbeit"... is this "von" also a "different" von than the one that is in combination with "nach"?. The only difference is that "kommen" makes sense with just an origin and fahren doesn't. There is no such thing as a fixed combination... unless you say it is connected specifically to "fahren" and even then: "Ich fahre aus dem Tunnel in die Sonne", "Ich fahre vom Steg auf die Fähre.", "Ich fahre mit dem Zug von Berlin ans Meer."

Comment: The 2 prepositions are independent. Which one is there depends on the verb only. Which one works alone depends on the verb only. There is NO special construction. Please provide proof, if you still think there is.

Comment: the only combination that can be called a double preposition is "von... bis..." for time... and even that is arguable.

Answer (score 7):

Contrary to what the other answer is claiming there is no such thing as "double prepositions that can't be split".
It is all just a convention.
It happened to be that way and now it is **nach** and not **zu**.

In German it is

> auf dem Bild,

in English

> in the picture

And to debunk the double preposition idea:

> Ich fahre (von Berlin) ans Meer.
>
> Ich komme von Arbeit (nach Hause).
>
> Ich laufe aus dem Wald auf eine Wiese.
>
> Ich gehe von mir zu dir.

The prepositions that are used depent ONLY on the location that follows, NOT on the other preposition that was used.
Whether or not I can skip one half of the location depends ONLY on the verb.

So... it is convention. There are some rule but there is also a lot that just has to be learned.
Searching for a deeper reason for such things is a waste of time.

Comment: Aber "im Spiegelbild" ;)

Comment: @Em1: stimmt, man könnte jetzt darüber philosophieren in wie weit ein reales 3D-Verhalten des Abbildes einen Einfluß auf die Präposition hat und in wie weit Deutsch und Englisch eine unterschiedliche starke Immersion beim betrachten 2-dimensionaler Abbildungen empfinden, was uns wiederrum zu interessanten Schlußfolgerungen hinsichtlich der Dominanz Hollywoods führen könnte :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is indeed very simple: Google Translate is wrong to suggest „von Englisch nach Deutsch“. It really is „aus dem Englischen ins Deutsche“.