# Translation of "Could you translate this into German?"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would you translate the sentence "Could you translate this into German?" into German?

(a) Könnten Sie das in Deutsch übersetzen?

(b) Könnten Sie das ins Deutsche übersetzen?

Comment: Related: [“von Englisch nach Deutsch” - why not “zu”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/7773/1224)

Comment: I would say "Könnten Sie das auf Deutsch übersetzen"... especially if "it" is short and mundane

Answer (score 5, accepted):

b would be right. `Man übersetzt ins <Sprache hier>`. And your version would be the formal version. A more casual version would be something like:

```
Könntest du das ins Deutsche übersetzen?
```

And maybe an even more casual example:

```
Übersetz das doch mal ins Deutsche
```

Comment: Is using the imperative as in your second proposal to be considered "*casual*"? I'd take this as a different translation, as it is an order and the former version is a request.

Comment: @alk: as the obligatory *please* is missing in the English source we may indeed assume this was an order rather than a request. This is quite nicely reflected by using imperative in German.

Comment: More casual would be: "Was heißt das auf Deutsch?" or "Und jetzt mal in/auf Deutsch bitte."

Comment: Why "ins Deutsche" and not "ins Deutsch"?

Comment: @karoshi http://german.about.com/od/nounsandcases/a/Adjectives-As-Nouns.htm